# How to find the interval of p such that the series is convergent?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

The question is as following:

> For what values of $p$ is the series convergent?
>   $$ \sum_{n=2}^\infty (-1)^{n-1}\frac{(\ln n)^p}{n^2}$$

What I have done so far:

1. Take Absolute Value (Test for Absolute Convergent)
2. Using Integration By Parts repeatedly (Do Integral Test)
   $$\int_{2}^\infty\frac{(\ln x)^p}{x^2}dx=
   \lim_{t\to\infty}\left[(\ln x)^p(-\frac{1}{x})+p(\ln x)^{p-1}(- \frac{1}{x})+p(p-1)(\ln x)^{p-2}(- \frac{1}{x})+...+p!(- \frac{1}{x})\right]_{2}^{t}$$

I found that the value of $p$ seems have no effect on the convergence of the series and my answer for this question is $[0,\infty)$ but when I tested it with WolframAlpha, I found it when $p=n$, it is not convergent.

And thus I know I may have made some mistakes.

So can anyone point out which part did I do it wrongly? It would be really appreciated :D

Thanks for you help!

Comment: $p$ is supposed to be a fixed real number.  You can't set it to $n$.

Comment: um...so is it my answer is correct? @saulspatz

Comment: It converges for $p\ge0$ by the alternating series test.   What about negative $p$?

Comment: oh that's also convergent by the alternating series test. thanks!! :)

Answer (score 2):

It is always convergent by comparison, indeed $$\frac{(\ln n)^p}{n^2} = o \left(\frac 1{n^{\frac32}}\right)$$

Comment: umm may I know what comparison have you made? I'm only a Yr1 student and don't know too much about the little o notation...

Comment: Direct test comparison series https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_comparison_test